# Using wild card in list to exclude similar terms

Tags: amazon-redshift

We'd like to exclude common and stop words in the word count query and some terms have a slight variation like "account", "accounts", "account.", etc. Is there a way to use something like a wildcard (such as _ for the LIKE function) in the exclusion list to exclude all variations? There are thousands of words and "account" is just one example.

Query:

```
SELECT subject
from subject_table
WHERE subject NOT IN ('', 'and', 'for', 'of', 'account')
```

Comment: postgres 8 <> redshift - redshift was a fork of an early postgres but has had many updates over that version and has its own architecture. please remove postgres tag and update your title accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `[REGEXP_INSTR][1]`.

```
SELECT subject
from subject_table
WHERE REGEXP_INSTR(subject, '(and|for|of|account.*)') = 0
```

Comment: Brilliant! Works like a charm!  Thank you, @Joe Harris!

Comment: Hi Joe, do you know how the following terms can be included in the REGEXP_INSTR() statement?  [Angle, I'm

Comment: You comment got cut off but the pipe `|` acts as an OR within the regex. `WHERE REGEXP_INSTR(subject, '(and|for|of|account.*|this.*|that|the|^other)') = 0`